# How to convert shapefile to vector EMF?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, emf

I want to convert a shapefile to an EMF file. The EMF file must be a vector image, not a raster image. Please suggest to me some good packages or tools.

Comment: Do you want to use EMF files in CAD ?? If yes then try leadtools may be useful for you..

Comment: @Sunil: the emf-format allows the embedding od raster-files. therefore some emf are actually only wrappers around a raster-file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't actually convert the shapefile in EMF, since shapefile data is composed by geometric features and related attributes. You can export a representation of that shapefile data (using features styles and labels) as EMF.

All you need is [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/) and [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), both [open-source software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source_software).

- Load your shapefile in Quantum GIS and [style it](http://docs.qgis.org/html/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#style-tab) as you please;
- Create a layout in the [print composer](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html), taking in consideration the scale you want your data in the emf. (Don't forget to hide the frame);
- Export it as SVG (If it gives you errors you can also export to PDF);
- Open it in Inkscape;
- Save it as EMF using File>Save as...